# Suplantar valores NULL con espacios

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp, linq-to-sql

Necesito suplantar los valores `null` que me devuelva la query de Linq con valores que no estén en `null`, pueden ser espacios, me es indiferente...

esta es la query:

```
Cliente cliente = ctx.Cliente.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Documento == dni);
```

Aquí la clase cliente:

```
public partial class Cliente
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Cliente()
        {
            this.Rel_Reserva_Asiento = new HashSet<Rel_Reserva_Asiento>();
            this.Ticket = new HashSet<Ticket>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TipoDocumentoId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Documento { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
        public string Domicilio { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LocalidadId { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Alta { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SexoId { get; set; }
        public string passwd { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Rel_Reserva_Asiento> Rel_Reserva_Asiento { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Ticket { get; set; }
    }
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: No necesariamente siempre son nulls algunos valores, puede variar.

Comment: Hola, a que tipos de valores NULL te refieres?. Lo que devuelve tu query de Linq es un objeto de tipo **Cliente**, te refieres a alguna de sus propiedades?. Por favor indica el código de la clase `Cliente`.

Comment: Exactamente, a sus propiedades nulleables

Comment: A una propiedad del tipo **Nullable<int>** no puedes asignarle espacios en blanco, que quieres asignarle en esos casos?. lo mismo para **Nullable<DateTime>**.

Comment: Le agregue 0 o datetime.Now. Resuelto

Answer (score 1):

Lo que creo que es mejor como comentan en la una respuesta anterior, primero haces el select y creas una nueva clase Cliente a la cual le asignas a las propiedades los valores obtenidos y en el caso que permita valores nulos preguntas si es el caso que tenga un valor null asignarle el nuevo valor. En el caso de int debes asignar un valor entero y en DateTime una fecha valida, en estos casos no debes asignar espacios en blanco ya que te marcara error de conversión de datos.

```
Cliente cliente = ctx.Cliente.Select(x => new Cliente() {
    Id = x.Id,
    Apellido = x.Apellido,
    Nombre =x.Nombre,
    TipoDocumentoId = x.TipoDocumentoId ?? 0,
    Documento = x.Documento ?? 0,
    FechaNacimiento = x.FechaNacimiento ?? DateTime.Now,
    Domicilio =x.Domicilio,
    LocalidadId = x.LocalidadId ?? 0,
    Telefono =x.Telefono,
    Email =x.Email,
    Alta = x.Alta ?? DateTime.Now,
    SexoId = x.SexoId ?? 0,
    passwd =x.passwd,
    Rel_Reserva_Asiento =x.Rel_Reserva_Asiento,
    Ticket =x.Ticket,
})
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Documento == dni);
```

Comment: ¿Y si agregas una breve explicación de ese código? Considera que aquí usuarios y visitantes tienen diferentes niveles y distintas experiencias con diversos lenguajes. Saludos :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de dos formas, la primera es con un .Select(), así

```
Cliente cliente = ctx.Cliente
.Select(x => new Cliente() {
    Propiedad_1 = x.Propiedad_1 != null ? x.Propiedad_1 : valor_a_reemplazar,
    Propiedad_2 = x.Propiedad_2 != null ? x.Propiedad_2 : valor_a_reemplazar,
})
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Documento == dni);
```

La otra forma es como exponen en una respuesta anterior:

```
Cliente cliente = ctx.Cliente.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Documento == dni);

cliente.?Propiedad_1 = cliente.Propiedad_1 ?? valor_a_reemplazar;
cliente.?Propiedad_2 = cliente.Propiedad_2 ?? valor_a_reemplazar;
```

Nótese que *valor_a_reemplazar* es un valor válido del mismo tipo que la propiedad a reemplzar.

Comment: En la primer forma no me deja hacerlo, Propiedad_1 = x.Propiedad_1 != null ? Propiedad_1 : valor_a_reemplazar, la Cuando coloco la ultima propiedad me da que no existe en el contexto actual.

Comment: Ya vi, me faltó poner x.Propiedad_1, voy a editar la respuesta.